# open cart configure config file

Tags: opencart, config

I have installed open cart on my demo subdomain server. 
config file changed by me is as follows

```
// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://demos.abc.com/artnkraft/');

// HTTPS
define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'https://demos.abc.com/artnkraft/');

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '/demos/artnkraft/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '/demos/artnkraft/system/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', '/demos/artnkraft/image/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '/demos/artnkraft/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '/demos/artnkraft/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '/demos/artnkraft/system/config/');
define('DIR_CACHE', '/demos/artnkraft/system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '/demos/artnkraft/system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '/demos/artnkraft/system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', '/demos/artnkraft/system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_UPLOAD', '/demos/artnkraft/system/storage/upload/');

// DB
define('DB_DRIVER', 'mysqli');
define('DB_HOSTNAME', 'localhost');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'abc'); 
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'abc@_password');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'abc_database');  
define('DB_PORT', '3306');
define('DB_PREFIX', 'oc_');
```

this gives error

```
Warning: require_once(/demos/artnkraft/system/startup.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/cloudusweb/public_html/demos/artnkraft/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/demos/artnkraft/system/startup.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/cloudusweb/public_html/demos/artnkraft/index.php on line 17
```

i have also change the admin config file. 
help me how to configure configre file to correct path

thanks in advance

Comment: Please follow this answer- http://forum.opencart.com/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=115012 Hope this help.

Comment: I was doing wrong at `// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://demos.abc.com/artnkraft/');`

should use `// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://demos.abc.com/artnkraft/');` 
Instead `// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'https://demos.abc.com/artnkraft/');`

See the difference at http => https